# SKScene not animating occasionally

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I'm using an `SKScene` and an `SKEmitterNode` to render particles in my app.

I'm having an issue where occasionally my scene appears to load, but the particles do not animate. I have a setup where in my NIB I have a view with it's class set to `SKScene`. This is then connected to my view controller class as an `IBOutlet`.

My `particleScene.m` my implementation looks like this:

```
@implementation particleScene {
    SKEmitterNode* emitter;
    bool emitting;
}

-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
        /* Setup your scene here */

        self.backgroundColor = [SKColor whiteColor];
        [self addChild:[self newExplosion:50 : 280]];

    }
    return self;
}


- (SKEmitterNode *) newExplosion: (float)posX : (float) posy
{

    emitter.name = @"explosion";

    emitter.targetNode = self.scene;

    emitter = [[SKEmitterNode alloc] init];
    [emitter setParticleTexture:[SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"spark.png"]];

    [emitter setParticleBirthRate:20];
    [emitter setParticleSpeedRange:0.2];

    [emitter setParticleLifetime:2.5];
    [emitter setParticleLifetimeRange:0.49];

    [emitter setParticlePositionRange:CGVectorMake(500, self.frame.size.height)];
    [emitter setPosition:CGPointMake(posX, posy)];

    [emitter setAlpha:0.8];
    [emitter setParticleAlphaRange:0.2];
    [emitter setParticleAlphaSpeed:-0.7];

    [emitter setParticleScale:0.2];
    [emitter setParticleScaleSpeed:0.45];
    [emitter setYAcceleration:35];

    return emitter;
}

-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {
    [emitter setParticleColor:[UIColor colorWithHue:drand48() saturation:1.0 brightness:1 alpha:0.5]];
    [emitter setParticleColorBlendFactor:1];
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
}

@end
```

Then, in my view controller's `viewDidAppear` method, I do this to present the scene:

```
SKView * skView = self.particleView;

// Create and configure the scene.
SKScene * scene = [sixthParticleScene sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;

// Present the scene.
[skView presentScene:scene];
```

Is there something that I'm missing here? Occasionally this works, but the majority of the time the scene loads and some particles appear, but they are static.

Comment: Why are you not using the SpriteKit Particle File template instead of creating the code yourself?

Comment: No particular reason. Just wanted to try it out in code. I have tried using a Particle File template and I get the same result, so I don't think that's the issue.

Comment: I just realized that your are setting the targetNode BEFORE emitter = [[SKEmitterNode alloc] init]; That might be your issue.